# How do I force SSRS to break *in* a tablix row instead of between?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am writing an SSRS report that contains a (nested) tablix.  The last row of the inner tablix can contain a "large" chunk of text (say, between half a page to 3 pages typically).

With, say, half a page's worth of text in the last row, the report looks great on the Report Server, but when I render it as a PDF, a newline gets inserted before the last row.  This puts that whole row/box on a page of its own.

What I want, instead, is for the row to remain attached to the rest of the tablix, and just render until it his the bottom of the page, and then do a newline and move on with the rest of the row.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue myself.  I clicked on the last row/cell in the tablix and disabled "Keep Together on One Page".  This allowed it to split in the middle, so it didn't need to jump to the next page to stay together.